# In TCPDF, this getAliasNbPages return value {:ptp:} so How can i get integer

Tags: php, tcpdf

In TCPDF vthis function show value {:ptp:} so How can i get interger.

So please help me. I need this value because i need apply some condition.

I have lot of checked documentation. But i can't found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You only can get an `alias` because you not know the total page number until the end of the document. TCPDF replace the placeholder alias at `$pdf->Output()` with the correct number.

Comment: Yeah that means this thing is not possible in TCPDF.